# How to get just extreme outer flags (outer most boxes) from an image using open cv?

Tags: python, opencv

So I'm trying to extract the boxes from this picture [Picture for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nMtNL.jpg). According to [open CV documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.0/d9/d8b/tutorial_py_contours_hierarchy.html), `RETR_EXTERNAL` should return "only extreme outer flags". Their words not mine. Which according to them returns only returns the eldest parent in each family. So I Assumed that using `RETR_EXTERNAL` would extract the table and button in the reference image.But when I use `RETR_EXTERNAL` it produces only the reference image (the image I linked to first) as the output. It's almost as if there's an invisible box around the whole image.
Any help is appreciated

---

Here's The Code If You Need It:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import argparse
import imutils
import nn 
from PIL import Image, ImageFont, ImageDraw, ImageEnhance
def sort_contours(cnts, method="left-to-right"):
    # initialize the reverse flag and sort index
    reverse = False
    i = 0

    # handle if we need to sort in reverse
    if method == "right-to-left" or method == "bottom-to-top":
        reverse = True

    # handle if we are sorting against the y-coordinate rather than
    # the x-coordinate of the bounding box
    if method == "top-to-bottom" or method == "bottom-to-top":
        i = 1

    # construct the list of bounding boxes and sort them from top to
    # bottom
    boundingBoxes = [cv2.boundingRect(c) for c in cnts]
    (cnts, boundingBoxes) = zip(*sorted(zip(cnts, boundingBoxes),
        key=lambda b:b[1][i], reverse=reverse))

    # return the list of sorted contours and bounding boxes
    return (cnts, boundingBoxes)
def box_extraction(img_for_box_extraction_path, cropped_dir_path):
    # Read the image
    img = cv2.imread('41.jpg', 0)
    (thresh, img_bin) = cv2.threshold(img, 128, 255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY|cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
    #print len(img_bin)

    img_bin =255-img_bin 
    cv2.imwrite("Image_bin.jpg",img_bin)
    # Defining a kernel length
    kernel_length = np.array(img).shape[1]/80
    #print kernel_length
    verticle_kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (1, kernel_length))

    # A horizontal kernel of (kernel_length X 1), which will help to detect all the horizontal line from the image.
    hori_kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (kernel_length, 1))

    # A kernel of (3 X 3) ones.
    kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (3, 3))

    # Morphological operation to detect vertical lines from an image
    img_temp1 = cv2.erode(img_bin, verticle_kernel, iterations=7)
    verticle_lines_img = cv2.dilate(img_temp1, verticle_kernel, iterations=7)
    cv2.imwrite("verticle_lines.jpg",verticle_lines_img)
    # Morphological operation to detect horizontal lines from an image
    img_temp2 = cv2.erode(img_bin, hori_kernel, iterations=7)
    horizontal_lines_img = cv2.dilate(img_temp2, hori_kernel, iterations=7)
    cv2.imwrite("horizontal_lines.jpg",horizontal_lines_img)

    # Weighting parameters, this will decide the quantity of an image to be added to make a new image.
    alpha = 0.6
    beta = 1.0 - alpha


    # This function helps to add two image with specific weight parameter to get a third image as summation of two image.
    img_final_bin = cv2.addWeighted(verticle_lines_img, alpha, horizontal_lines_img, beta, 0.0)
    img_final_bin = cv2.erode(~img_final_bin, kernel, iterations=2)
    (thresh, img_final_bin) = cv2.threshold(img_final_bin, 128, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)



    # Find contours for image, which will detect all the boxes
    im2, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(img_final_bin, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    # Sort all the contours by top to bottom.
    #(contours, boundingBoxes) = sort_contours(contours, method="top-to-bottom")
```

Comment: Show, plz, img_final_bin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.2/d4/d73/tutorial_py_contours_begin.html):

> In OpenCV, finding contours is like finding white object from black background. So remember, object to be found should be white and background should be black.

findContours searches first for white objects. Thus the outermost contour is the white background. You can easily solve this by inverting the image using `img = cv2.bitwise_not(img)` or using `cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV` when thresholding:

Result:

[image]

Example code:

```
    import numpy as np 
    import cv2
    #load the image:  
    img = cv2.imread("box.jpg") 
    # create grayscale
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    # threshold image to remove noise and create an inverted mask
    ret,mask = cv2.threshold(gray,230,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
    #Find contours (external only):  
    im, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(mask, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)  
    #draw contours on original image
    cv2.drawContours(img, contours, -1, (0,0,255), thickness=2)
    # show image
    cv2.imshow("Image", img)

    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Note: you can also load the image as grayscale and skip creating one, but I used it here so I could draw more obvious red boxes.

Answer (score 0):

### An updated code of J.D. that worked for me

```
import numpy as np 
import cv2

img = cv2.imread("image_1.jpg") 

## create grayscale
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

## threshold image to remove noise and create an inverted mask with with OTSU
mask = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

## Find contours (external only):  
## Since the cv2.findContours has been updated to return only 2 parameters
contours, hierarchy= cv2.findContours(mask, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE) 

## draw contours on original image
cv2.drawContours(img, contours, -1, (255,0,0), thickness=2)

## show image
cv2.imshow("Image", img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```